# Upgrade Beta Badge to a Gold Badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Given that the number will *never* change, why not give everyone who was in the Beta a nice permanently shiny gold rather than a tarnish-able silver?

Just an idea.

Comment: -1:just because you can't be happy with something that no one else after the beta will ever get...

Comment: Just FYI: I was not in the beta, and would not benefit from this suggestion.

Comment: +1 I like this.  I would not benefit either but I feel it does deserve sold rather than silver

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, please don't rub it in any further.

*<sad face>*

Comment: Agreed! I am very upset I've never been invited to participate in a beta :-(

Comment: Actually, I have the beta badge on SF and SU, but I don't really care about them. :P

Comment: @mmyers Really, you don't care about them? Can I have one? Please? Pretty please? I'll buy one for 1,000 "Exp"!

Comment: Everyone was invited @josh

Comment: @Downvoter Not to the SO beta. (Though if you were already on SO invites for the others were automatic.)

Comment: @michael http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/

Comment: I thought badges were awarded based on difficulty, not rarity. The Beta badge wouldn't have been -hard- to get, per se (you simply had to join), so it wouldn't be suited for Gold... yet it is a special badge and rare, so it wouldn't be suited for Bronze... I think Silver fits it perfectly.

Comment: I had the beta badge on SF, but when the criteria were change it got taken away :(

Comment: @Downvoter Well, you did say "everyone". "I am sending out emails to the first 100 people for the private Stack Overflow beta; the email contains the password necessary to log in..." Sounds like a private invite to me, which would _not_ include everyone.

Comment: @Michael: The way to be invited was to email Jeff when he asked for betas. Or wait until [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/08/bad-news-good-news/).

Comment: @mmyers Aw, it's my own bloody fault. I _knew_ I should have checked that blog every flippin' day. <grin>

Comment: @Downvoter: Ahhh. Either I wasn't around yet or I didn't read the blog.

Answer (score 4):

> Given that the number will never change,

Why not just get rid of the whole badge? It's the same as rewarding a badge to everyone celebrating his/her birthday on 26th of the month (*cough*).

Comment: I don't think it's the same at all. It marks those who have been with SO since the beginning (or before the beginning, depending on how you look at it)

Comment: Well.. the idea is that these people are special; they participated in the Beta and helped make SOFU what it is. So here's a shiny badge. My point is that being a Beta tester is rare and will never be obtainable by anyone. Gold badge!  On second thought.... bronze badge.

Comment: That would be more special than the gold badge. Platina badge? Diamond? Kryptonite?

Comment: Couldn't agree more; it's like the current phenomenon of award prizes to kids just for showing up.

Comment: @BalusC: I'll probably forget by Wednesday (sorry :p), so Happy Birthday!

Comment: @Andy: you'll then be 2 months too late ;) [It's March](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528069#2528069).

Comment: @BalusC: lol, I misread the *(cough)* at the end of your answer as a hint ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a silver (and should probably stay that way) because of the number of people that have it.  If you look at it on SO relative to the existing gold badges, at 2602 there are ~2.5 times the number of people who have the beta badge than the closest gold badge (Famous Question) coming in currently at 1037.

There was hoopla around the public beta launch, enough that 2606 people got in on it (actively anyway).  I'd wager that even more people saw the hoopla about the launch of SF and SU which would be further reason to keep them at silver.  Sometimes we miss out.  Life's a *itch, eat waffles!